# Android ActionbarSherlock - when using ListNavigation, should the onNavigationItemSelected() be called when the Activity starts?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using ListNavigation and the onNavigationItemSelected() method gets called when the Activity starts.

Here is my method:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) 
{        
    if ( itemPosition == 1 )
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent); 
    }
    else
    if ( itemPosition == 2 )
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LearnActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);          
    }        
    else
    if ( itemPosition == 3 )
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServicesActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);          
    }                

    return true;
}
```

But something is obviously wrong with it. Should these intents not be in that method? Or am I getting something very mixed up?

The behavior I am getting is that when I try to go to another activity, it always brings it back to the starting activity.

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Can you call activities with ABS ? In every example I've seen it's always done with fragments.

Comment: @IanB Never used fragments. But I am kind of suspecting something else may be wrong. Do you know of a good example. I've been Googling, but lots of stuff there is far from the examples inside ActionSherlock.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a good example for ABS but this is very good for fragments in general: http://marakana.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial

Comment: Please have a look at the Jake Wharton sample for ABS): https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments  I'm not saying you can't do what you are trying to do - just haven't seen it done that way...

Comment: I think there is some kind of loop going on where on starting the activity, the onNavigationItemSelected() is called, and I have to figure out how to get out of that loop.

Comment: Weirdest part is the strange behavior happens if I navigate to that activity through pressing a button on the app, and not during the selection of the ListNavigation

Comment: I've been looking for examples of other people doing this ... so far nothing ...

Comment: I think I figured it out ...it might have been something stupid on my part LOL..still debugging :)

Comment: OK I would be interested to see your posted example / solution

Answer (score 0):

The fix ended up this workaround:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="locations">
        <item>Navigation</item>        
        <item>Home</item>
        <item>Learn</item>
        <item>Services</item>
        <item>Next Steps</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and then

```
**  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) 
  {        
      if ( itemPosition == 1 )
      {
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(ServicesActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
          ServicesActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);            
      }
      else
      if ( itemPosition == 2 )
      {
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(ServicesActivity.this, LearnActivity.class);
          ServicesActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);            
      }        
      else
      if ( itemPosition == 3 )
      {
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(ServicesActivity.this, ServicesActivity.class);
          ServicesActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);            
      }        
      else
      if ( itemPosition == 4 )
      {
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(ServicesActivity.this, GiveBackActivity.class);
          ServicesActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
      }                

      return true;
  }
```

The issue was that sometimes the id that was called was triggering wrong intents. So I had to be careful about it. Also, I made the first array item arbitrary so if the page loaded and id was 0, I knew not to do anything.